# Updating multiple innerhtml variables with generic function

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to combine many similar functions into one but having some difficulty.

This is an example of one of the original functions (called by a button press).

```
    function ADD_ONE(Variable_Name){
Variable_Name += 1;
        document.getElementById(Variable_Name).innerHTML = Variable_Name;
   };
```

And here is my attempt at the replacement

```
function ADD_ONE(Variable_Name){
Variable_Name += 1;
        document.getElementById(Variable_Name).innerHTML = Variable_Name;
   };
```

This causes an error:

```
ref(v1.0).html:744 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at ADD_ONE
```

It's probably something quite simple I am missing, but as still relatively new to Javascript would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

What is your HTML? That error usually means that your page does not have the element that you are trying to call `document.getElementById()` on, because it will return null if the element does not exist, and null does not have an innerHTML property as it is not an element. However, this is impossible to verify without seeing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order at which you're changing the Variable_Name you're altering it before getting the original element so just put:

```
var element = document.getElementById(Variable_Name);

Variable_Name += 1;

element.innerHtml += Variable_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

because when you +1 your variable, after that when you want get this element, this element not exist in DOM,

```
Variable_Name += 1
```

this line is incorrect, and you have not this element in DOM